# weight conversion program failed

Tags: python-3.x

```
weight = float(input("weight: "))
unit = input("(K)g or (L)bs: ")

if unit.upper == "K":
    converted = weight*2.2
    print("Weight in Lbs: " + str(converted))
else:
    converted = weight/2.2
    print("Weight in kgs: " + str(converted))
print("Conversion done")
```

result:

> weight: 15
> (K)g or (L)bs: k
> Weight in kgs: 6.8181818181818175
> Conversion done

I am a beginner and trying to convert the weight but only else block is executing not the if block. Why?

Comment: TIP: If you see that your `if` condition is not getting executed, try printing out the value to see what it actually is. So in this case, print out `unit.upper` before the `if`, and you'll see it's not the string value but something like "built-in function or method". Then you'll realize you are not comparing it to the string value.

Answer (score 1):

```
weight = float(input("Enter weight: "))
unit = input("Entered Value is (K)g or  (L)bs: ")

if unit.upper() == "K":
    converted = weight*2.2
    print("Weight in Lbs: " + str(converted))
else:
    converted = weight/2.2
    print("Weight in kgs: " +  str(converted))
print("Conversion done")
```

You need to use if unit.upper() instead of unit.upper otherwise it will always go to the else statement as if will deem input to be false

Comment: @AsmaNaaz, if you found the answer helpful you should upvote it / mark it as correct so that others know it has been answered and can see what worked incase they have the same question.

Answer (score -1):

You need to use `unit.upper()` with the `()`.

`str.upper` is the *name* of the method, but you want to actually *call* the method, which requires the parens.

As you have it, `if unit.upper == 'K'` is checking 'is our method `unit.upper` equal to the string capital K'?